# PhoneAuthProvider: Sms auto retrieval timed-out

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am not in Prod environment. Still debugging the App. All of a sudden in the middle of testing I have started receiving -

PhoneAuthProvider: Sms auto retrieval timed-out.

Code around Firebase Phone Auth is not even touched at all since weeks. Say 5-6 hrs back I could have SMS received but this problem started just 2-3 hrs back.

Is there any setting got altered or some setting has got expired like - SHA1 debug env key ?

How could I determine, what is going wrong with functionality & all of a sudden has stopped working ?

Thanks & regards,
Vikram.

Comment: Though, I say not in Prod, but I have deployed server side / web components to Google Cloud. At present I am testing my app by pointing it over to Google Cloud.

Comment: Now here I have got another data points. I could see, Phone based authentication is working on one setup but ceased to work on another setup since yesterday.
Phone where this functionality is not working - Karbon Titanium S5.
Android 4.1.2
Google Play Services - 11.5.09 (034-164803921)
This has Airtel network.

Same code for Phone based authentication at present working at - 
LAVA Iris X8 L - Android 5.1
Google Play Services - 11.5.09 (236-164803921)
This has Idea cellular network.

Comment: Now what I did to ascertain if it is network problem or phone device - Google Play Services / Android configuration.
From Android 5.1... I have mentioned the phone number of sim which Android 4.1.2 device is holding. I have got the same error as - PhoneAuthProvider: Sms auto retrieval timed-out
Just to reaffirm this, I gave another number, (which is not on Android) but having another network, BSNL in this instance. To my surprise this BSNL device has got SMS.
This proves phone configuration is nothing to do with; SMS auto retrieval getting timed out; but it has with the phone carrier n/w.

Comment: Having confirmed that, problem is independent of Android configuration, wondering how come reputed network like Airtel would stop sending SMS? Also, then I have tried sending SMS to this erring device from another phone. It did not reach. Wondered, the problem was more with the device than network. This is where I have found solution.
https://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/295287-suddenly-not-receiving-texts.html
Just in quick, suggested... Settings->Apps->All->Messaging ... Force Stop. Restart. ... It worked.
Issue is not related with Firebase-Auth